# Allow all file types for upload

Tags: plugins, uploads

I'm using Wordpress 3.4.2 for a private blog, i.e. one on which only I can post. Now, Wordpress prevents me from uploading certain file types (like C# source files). As far as I understand it, there's a white-list that defines what can be uploaded.

Is there a plugin that can extend - or better, even disable - this white-list?

All other answers tell me I should edit my theme but I'd rather have a plugin for that (so that I don't need to edit all my themes).

Also, I found [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ap-extended-mime-types/) but, again, it requires me to edit some file on my server (that's probably overwritten when the plugin is updated).

So, is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, toscho's answer doesn't work - at least not in Wordpress 3.4 and above.

The correct solution is the following:

```
#
# For this, see: wp-includes/capabilities.php > map_meta_cap()
#
function wpse_6533_map_unrestricted_upload_filter($caps, $cap) {
  if ($cap == 'unfiltered_upload') {
    $caps = array();
    $caps[] = $cap;
  }

  return $caps;
}

add_filter('map_meta_cap', 'wpse_6533_map_unrestricted_upload_filter', 0, 2);
```

Comment: Hi, where should I put the code above? Will it work if I put it on my functions.php?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza Yes, you can put it in `functions.php` of your theme. But then, this will only work as long as your theme is active AFAIK.

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Comment: Still it disallows me to upload, say, ".exe" files "for security reasons". (Can be my Real media library plugin issue?) Admin user. Allowing mime types specificly through upload_mimes filter works.

Comment: I've tried this with WP 5.7.2, attempting to upload JSON files, and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a plugin or add this to the config file, but for 3.9.2 this worked for me.

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

Comment: This is the Core way of doing it. +1

Comment: Confirmed to work in Wordpress 4.1 as well!

Comment: This, in wp-config.php. I really don't understand why it isn't the default, at least for administrators.

Comment: Still it disallows me to upload, say, ".exe" files "for security reasons". (Can be my Real media library plugin issue?) Admin user. Allowing mime types specificly through upload_mimes filter works.

Comment: What security implications are there for this? Does flicking this setting off leave my site vulnerable to malicious script uploads etc?

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes - I am sure there are security concerns.   Anytime you allow more things, more things can damage you.    I deal with a lot of private sites behind SSO so it isn't much concern to me.   But for public site you would not have an upload ability on the front end or you would limit the upload script on the front end to whatever you whitelist.   This setting starts your site "fresh" - and given C# requirement basically you have to do this first.   I have a whitelist script too but that isn't the question.

Answer (score 3):

Filter `'user_has_cap'` and set `'unfiltered_upload'` to 1.

Sample code *not tested:*

```
/*
Plugin Name: Remove Uploads Filter
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67225/allow-all-file-types-for-upload
Description: Disables white-list filter for uploads
Version: 1.0
Author: WPSE - @toscho
*/

add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wpse_67225_unfiltered_upload' );

function wpse_67225_unfiltered_upload( $caps )
{
    $caps['unfiltered_upload'] = 1;
    return $caps;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this with WP 5.7.2, attempting to upload JSON files, and unfortunately it doesn't work.